# This error occurred: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: You do not have the necessary permissions to disable this portal user

Tags: community, profile, user, partner-communities, partner-portal

I am trying to disable a customer portal user from partner community and I am getting the below error:
*You do not have the necessary permissions to disable this portal user.*

I have created a flow which updates the user record with isActive = false and isPortalEnabled = false, but it throws the said error.

How can I give permission to the partner user profile to disable portal user?

Comment: To create or update external users you need "Manage External Users permission." permission and also to deactivate users you need "Manage Internal Users" permission .

Comment: But I don’t see Manage external users permission on the partner profile. Where can I find it? I checked in the App permission but cannot find it.

Comment: I tried assigning a permission set with Manage External Users Permission but got the error. The error is attached below.
: Can't assign permission set B2B Community User Permission Set to user Admin Test User 9. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Manage External Users